# asp.net, how can i go from localhost/Controller1/Index to localhost/Controller2/Details/{ID}?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, actionlink

I am trying to go from `https://localhost:44383/Reservations/Index` to `https://localhost:44383/Bikes/Details/{Id}`
But I don't know what html `actionlink` i need.

I thought this was the right one: `@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Bikes", new { Id = item.Reservation.Bike_Id })`

Can someone tell me how to go from Reservation controller to details controller and give details and id as parameter?

`@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details" , "Bikes")` brings me to `localhost/Bikes/Details`. But I need the id at the back as well

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Bike bike = db.Bikes.Find(id);
        if (bike == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(bike);
    }
```

Comment: The first details is what you see as a link. `@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details" , "Bikes")` this brings me to `localhost/Bikes/Details`. But i need the id at the back as well :(

Comment: Lets see the controller action the one you want to call

Comment: updated with the controller of bike details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Bikes", "Details", new { id  = item.Reservation.Bike_Id }, null)
```

Note that I've used a lowercase 'i' in the id parameter passed. I also think you have the controller name and the action name the wrong way around here.

Also worth noting that as you are passing parameters, you should use a null overload to correct the action link.

Comment: that brings me to `https://localhost:44383/Reservations/Details?Length=5`

Comment: that brings me to `https://localhost:44383/Reservations/Bikes?Length=7`

Comment: @kevin In that case, what you will need is an overload. Adding `null` as the forth input in this link should solve your problem. This will be because if you use other parameters, it assumes the third argument is the route values and the 4th are the html attributes. Adding the 5th will correct this.